# Bundle HERE Maps API yarn install with stimulus js

Tags: yarnpkg, here-api, heremaps

Is it possible to install Bundle HERE Maps API by yarn?
I use stimulus js and I want to use here maps with it.

I found only for nmp https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.30.9/dev_guide/topics/get-started-bundling.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to install the HERE Maps API bundle using Yarn. Only NPM (Node Package Manager) is available so far.

If you are looking to use the HERE Maps API, you can proceed with the installation using NPM. You can include the required packages and dependencies in your project's package.json file and then run the npm install command to install the HERE Maps API bundle and its dependencies.